# Record All IP's Forwarded To Port

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding

I have a `Netgear WNDR 4300` and have multiple ports forwarded for RDC, Websites, Web Streaming excetera.  Is there a way (I am open to using `DDWRT` if that is the only way) - to capture IP Addresses that are being forwarded?

For example, let's say that IP XX.XXX.XXX.109 hit my router and tried to access port `3068` - could I log the IP and the port it attempted to access?

Comment: What you want is not possible with the default firmware that comes on the router you have.  DDWRT allows for a good  amount of logging, and anything that isn't logged, likely could be logged given the correct code and/or script.

Comment: @Ramhound - can you illustrate how I would do such using DDWRT?

Comment: Can you type **ipset** and see if that is a valid command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said forwarded so use rule #2, but you might need 1 also.

1. iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3068 -j  LOG --log-prefix "short descript goes here " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
2. iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3068 -j  LOG --log-prefix "short descript goes here " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options

I think the description is limited to 24 characters.
If the router is rebooted you will need to re-enter it.